# Using jackson object identity mapping over multiple documents

Tags: initialization, jackson, identity

I'm working on a library where I want to convert a series of JSON documents into an object model. All the objects are represented by unique identifiers and I'd like to use Jackson's @JsonIdentityInfo annotation to allow the resulting objects to reference each other. Each object has an id

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="_id")
abstract public class SDBObject extends JSONSerialisable {
  /** The (mongodb) object identifier */
  @JsonProperty("_id")
  private String id;
...
}
```

and what I would like to do is then be able to link objects with

```java
public class SDBStream extends SDBObject {
  /** The owning node */
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  @JsonProperty("nid")
  private SDBNode node;
...
}
```

This would be easy enough if everything came across as a single JSON document. However, I receive various objects as a series of type-specific documents.

What I would like to do is pre-load the identity mapping system with a dictionary of existing ids and objects, so that subsequently decoded documents will be able to use the existing objects when an id is encountered.

Where should I be injecting this information into the ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the easiest thing to do is provide a subclass of the DefaultDeserializationContext that extends findObjectId to bind known objects. Something along the lines of:

```java
public class SDBDeserializationContext extends DefaultDeserializationContext {
  private SDBContext context;

  public SDBDeserializationContext(DeserializerFactory df,
      DeserializerCache cache, SDBContext context) {
    super(df, cache);
    this.context = context;
  }

  public SDBDeserializationContext(SDBDeserializationContext src,
      DeserializerFactory factory) {
    super(src, factory);
    this.context = src.context;
  }

  public SDBDeserializationContext(SDBDeserializationContext src,
      DeserializationConfig config, JsonParser jp, InjectableValues values) {
    super(src, config, jp, values);
    this.context = src.context;
  }

  @Override
  public DefaultDeserializationContext with(DeserializerFactory factory) {
    return new SDBDeserializationContext(this, factory);
  }

  @Override
  public DefaultDeserializationContext createInstance(
      DeserializationConfig config, JsonParser jp, InjectableValues values) {
    return new SDBDeserializationContext(this, config, jp, values);
  }

  @Override
  public ReadableObjectId findObjectId(Object id, ObjectIdGenerator<?> generator) {
    ReadableObjectId oid = super.findObjectId(id, generator);

    if (oid.item == null && this.context != null) {
      SDBObject object = this.context.findBinding(id);
      if (object != null)
        try {
          oid.bindItem(object);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to bind " + object + " to " + id, ex);
        }
    }
    return oid; 
  }
}
```